# Remove empty directory in cvs which only added

Tags: cvs

I have added mistakenly empty directory with tree strcture into cvs. I would like to remove this directory. is there anyway to remove empty directory into cvs

Answer (score 0):

**cvs export always removes empty directories**

if directory is not empty you cannot remove it

Comment: But I have added those file not commit those file